# Parse column value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a `Varchar` column with the value as mentioned below. How can i parse this string into columns

This string in a column

```
<item id="1" value="1"><item id="2" value="6"><item id="4" value="8">
```

into

```
Item ID  value
--------------
1        1
2        6
4        8
```

Comment: If you change your column to `xml` then you can trivially achieve this with xQuery.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 2):

Your data resembles XML fragment. And it is not well-formed.

All what you need is to compose XML on the fly. After that XQuery makes it very easy (as @Larnu pointed out it already). No need to parse anything.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, tokens NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT @tbl (tokens) VALUES
(N'<item id="1" value="1"><item id="2" value="6"><item id="4" value="8">');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT c.value('@id', 'INT') AS id
    , c.value('@value', 'INT') AS [value]
FROM @tbl t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root>' + 
    REPLACE(tokens, '>', '/>') + 
    '</root>' AS XML)) AS t1(x)
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/root/item') AS t2(c);
```

**Output**

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 4 | 8 |